# MongoDB aggregation with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, aggregation

I have a User model and I want to perform generic aggregation. mean any array of object I pass to this function it executes.

this is the sample of getUser function

```
public async getUser(aggregate: object): Promise<ResponseDTO> {
     let response = {} as ResponseDTO;
     const [err, user] = await To(User.aggregate(aggregate));
     if (user) {
         response = { success: true, data: user, message: "User fround" };
     }
     else
         response = { success: false, message: "User not fround" };
     return response;
}
```

and I pass this as a Parameter

```
const query = [
  {
     $match: {
        name:"Jon"
     }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      _id:1  
    }
  }
]
const userRes = await getUser(query);
```

But I'm not able to run the program it's giving me syntax error on getUser function

*(method) Model<any, any, any>.aggregate(pipeline?: any[] | undefined): Aggregate<any[]> (+1 overload)

Argument of type 'Aggregate<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise'.
Type 'Aggregate<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise': [Symbol.toStringTag], finally*

I tried to change object to any, Array or Array in getUser parameter

here is the SS of the Error [image]

PS: ***I'm using node with typescript and IDE is VSCode***

Comment: Can you post the entire error (properly formatted)? Also what libraries are you using in this snippet?

Comment: @Max, I just updated the question

Comment: Question is misleading, you are not looking for MongoDB but for Mongoose. Please reformulate the question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose provides ***PipelineStage*** interface for pipes We can use that right away

```
import { PipelineStage } from "mongoose";

public async getUser(aggregate: PipelineStage[]):
Promise<ResponseDTO> {
     let response = {} as ResponseDTO;
     const [err, user] = await User.aggregate(aggregate);
     if (user) {
         response = { success: true, data: user, message: "User found" };
     }
     else
         response = { success: false, message: "User not found" };
     return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose queries have their own types, and you should use those types to avoid such errors.

You can import those types for anything you need directly from Mongoose package.

I strongly recommend using the Typegoose package, which helps to create fully typed MongoDB schemas. and by that allow you to use those types as a response, find and update queries and much more!
reference:
https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide

Example for your usage with correct type:

```
import { FilterQuery } from 'mongoose';

public async getUser(aggregate: FilterQuery<ResponseDTO>): Promise<ResponseDTO> {
     let response = {} as ResponseDTO;
     const [err, user] = await To(User.aggregate(aggregate));
     if (user) {
         response = { success: true, data: user, message: "User fround" };
     }
     else
         response = { success: false, message: "User not fround" };
     return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried this too. not woking for me